# Google Cloud Platform: Is there a way to protect Deleting Instance with 2fa?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, console

Currently deleting instance only take 2 clicks and session on console.cloud.google.com is not destroyed even browser is closed even for days.

Some devs might forget to logout and his teammate/child/someone else could accidentally (or not) open his console.cloud.google.com account while he is in the toilet. Only 2 clicks away his instance and all data in it could be deleted by mistake (or not).

To prevent such case, is there anyway to protect Deleting Instance with 2fa?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=312) to allow the session timeout of your Google Cloud Console.

The Console asks for confirmation before deleting instances but [2-Step verification](https://www.google.ca/landing/2step/) is only enforced when you sign in from a new device (you can choose to have this device remembered for 30 days).

As a workaround you might be able to use [3rd party tools](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/google-softwaretips/want-to-automatically-logout-of-gmail-or-google-account/) to force the sign out.